# 'module' object is not callable issue

Tags: python

For some reason I'm getting a module object is not callable error on this code. I am not understanding the reason behind this error? What could be the reason for this error? I looked online and found a common explanation that this could be due to similar module and function names. But I am unable to fix it.

```
def Dataset_loader(DIR, RESIZE, sigmaX=10):
    IMG = []
    read = lambda imname: np.asarray(Image.open(imname).convert("RGB"))
    for IMAGE_NAME in tqdm(os.listdir(DIR)):
        PATH = os.path.join(DIR,IMAGE_NAME)
        _, ftype = os.path.splitext(PATH)
        if ftype == ".png":
            img = read(PATH)
           
            img = cv2.resize(img, (RESIZE,RESIZE))
           
            IMG.append(np.array(img))
    return IMG

ben_train = np.array(Dataset_loader('D:/regionGrowing_MLT/AllSavedRGBImages/Training/Benign',224))
mal_train = np.array(Dataset_loader('D:/regionGrowing_MLT/AllSavedRGBImages/Training/Malignant',224))
ben_test = np.array(Dataset_loader('D:/regionGrowing_MLT/AllSavedRGBImages/Test/Benign',224))
mal_test = np.array(Dataset_loader('D:/regionGrowing_MLT/AllSavedRGBImages/Test/Malignant',224))
```

The above code is throwing me the following error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-0c6ae6585a38> in <module>
     13     return IMG
     14 
---> 15 ben_train = np.array(Dataset_loader('D:/regionGrowing_MLT/AllSavedRGBImages/Training/Benign',224))
     16 mal_train = np.array(Dataset_loader('D:/regionGrowing_MLT/AllSavedRGBImages/Training/Malignant',224))
     17 ben_test = np.array(Dataset_loader('D:/regionGrowing_MLT/AllSavedRGBImages/Test/Benign',224))

<ipython-input-25-0c6ae6585a38> in Dataset_loader(DIR, RESIZE, sigmaX)
      2     IMG = []
      3     read = lambda imname: np.asarray(Image.open(imname).convert("RGB"))
----> 4     for IMAGE_NAME in tqdm(os.listdir(DIR)):
      5         PATH = os.path.join(DIR,IMAGE_NAME)
      6         _, ftype = os.path.splitext(PATH)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyforest\_importable.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     47     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     48         self.__maybe_import__()
---> 49         return eval(self.__imported_name__)(*args, **kwargs)
     50 
     51     def __repr__(self, *args, **kwargs):

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: What is ```tqdm```?

Comment: `tqdm` is a module. You need to import it like this: `from tqdm import tqdm`. I think you did `import tqdm`, which means you are using the module, not the function.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have imported tqdm as `import tqdm`. Now you are trying to call the module in your script.
What you have to do is `from tqdm import tqdm`. Know you are importing the function from the module which have both the same name. It's quite common in python packages and you have to pay attention to it.
Alternatively you could also call it like `tdqm.tdqm(...)`. As then you would explicitly state the module and the function.